# Cordova install plugin

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I need to download plugins for my cordova project, but everything I try to do install, for example

```
call cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.camera
```

My command prompt echoes an error:

```
using node version 0.10.29 which has been deprecated. please upgrade to the
latest node version available <v6.x is recommended>
```

and I have absolutely no idea how to go about installing it. I have tried updating my cordova to the latest version as well, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install latest Nodejs from here: https://nodejs.org/en/download/ which installs latest npm.

According to the [repo](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera) of the plugin you're using, the command is deprecated. Use this instead: `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera`

Comment: Hi! There's a new error saying Error: Registry returned 404 for GET on https://registry.npmjs.org/org.apache.cordova.file

Comment: Hello! I have solved this after you provided me a new command. Thank you so much!

Comment: @03131992 Glad I could help :)

Comment: hi! it works now but somehow my camera has failed to turn on in my sdk? They keep saying it stops working

Comment: @03131992 Please post this issue as a new question, to avoid mixing topics

Answer (score 1):

> "please upgrade to the
>   latest node version available v6.x is recommended"

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
```

Instead of using "stable", you could specify a desired version:

```
sudo n 0.8.21
```

For more information visit: https://davidwalsh.name/upgrade-nodejs

Comment: Hi! it works now but now I get an error saying Error: Registry returned 404 for GET on https://registry.npmjs.org/org.apache.cordova.file